# Skills classification in resume

Tags: resume

I need help how to classify skills in resume and is this correct :

```
Strong
iOS : Objective-C, swift.

Familiar
PHP, C#, ASP.net MVC, JAVA.

Other
Git, JSON, Rest API, UML, Sql, SCRUM, Sketch
```

Update :

```
Language
 - Extensive experience in Objective-C and swift.
 - Familiar with PHP, C# and JAVA

Frameworks
Cocoa Touch, Laravel and ASP.net MVC.

Other
Git, JSON, Rest API, UML, Sql, SCRUM, Sketch
```

Comment: That's as good a system as any other. In the expedience section you can go into more details about what kinds of things you've done with which languages and platforms.

Comment: Why are you listing skills you aren't even familiar with on a resume? You may as well include several dead languages (Ancient Greek COBOL etc.) to spice things up.

Comment: @djechlin which skills you are talking about ? All skills I've included I've used it in more then 3 project at least  so do you think I'm not fimiliar with ?

Comment: You have a "Familiar" section. It is followed by an "Other" section. It stands to reason that the skills under "Other" you are not "Familiar" with.

Comment: @djechlin check my update please.

Answer (score 1):

This may vary by employer, but if I saw that on a resume I would have no idea what you meant by it and so the CV would go on the reject pile.

I would suggest something like:

- Extensive experience in Objective-C etc
- Familiar with PHP etc

and regarding your final category, I would either leave it out altogether, or give some reason why it should be in, as an employer will look at those and think you don't have extensive experience with them and you are not familiar with them, so do you just know the name? So possibly:

- Limited experience with JSON etc

Comment: For the final category it's not classification based on knowledge level because JSON, UML or Rest API ... can be used with any language. I meant that I've good experience with those tools

Comment: check my update please

Answer (score 1):

Bluntly, each category you have described is terrible.

**Strong**: Who do you think is going to believe your blanket assertion about yourself? That claim should be substantiated over projects you have completed and responsibilities you have held.

**Familiar**: I assume you are not familiar with these skills.

**Other**: I have no idea why you are listing skills on your resume that you are openly admitting you are not even familiar with.

*Personally* I don't include a skills section but I spell out all the technologies used in each project I discuss on my resume. If you insist, omit the "Other," don't separate "strong" and "familiar" and leave the rest of your resume to substantiate which skills are strong. Only include a language if you can write a "hello world" on a whiteboard and answer the question "So what's something you wrote in it?"